# MySQL: Get only objects with currently not active plan

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create a query that gets me only those object ids, who belog to a plan that's current status is quitted (-1). This can be done via the begin field, but i don't know how to exclude past quitted plans. Of course there can be many plans and many objects. I trimmed the original structure down to this:

```
TABLE objects
--------------------
id, title, xid, state
1, a, 6, 1
2, b, 6, 1
3, c, 6, 1
4, d, 2, 1

TABLE plans
--------------------
xid, status, begin
6, 1, 2017
2, -1, 2017
6, -1, 2016
```

This query gets all objects that have a plan which status is quitted (-1).
Problem is, that this query also gets all objects ids if the quitted plan lies in the past and the current active plan ist fine.

```
SELECT o.id
FROM objects AS o
LEFT JOIN plans AS p ON o.xid=p.xid
WHERE p.status = -1
ORDER BY p.begin
```

This outputs:
1,2,3,4
But it should only output
4

I want this because in the end i want a query that deactivates (o.state=0) all objects that currently don't have an active plan.

Comment: why do you use LIKE? use = insted since you are looking for an exact match

Comment: updated question. it was from my original structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the current status for each `xid` by doing:

```
select p.*
from plans p
where p.begin = (select max(p2.begin) from plans p2 where p2.xid = p.xid);
```

You can get the objects in such plans using `join`, `exist`, or `in`:

```
select o.*
from objects o
where o.xid in (select p.xid
                from plans p
                where p.begin = (select max(p2.begin) from plans p2 where p2.xid = p.xid) and
                      p.status = -1
               );
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed the second query for the original structure and it seams to work. But how can i use that subselect thing in an update that deactivates all objects with no active plan?

Answer (score 0):

You can add another filter to your existing query to filter out those that are active.

```
SELECT o.id
FROM objects AS o
LEFT JOIN plans AS p ON o.xid=p.xid
WHERE p.status = -1
AND p.xid NOT IN (SELECT xid FROM plans WHERE status = 1)
ORDER BY p.begin
```